# How to equalize volumes of lines by different voice actors using different setups?

Tags: audio, voice, fmod

I have 500 voice lines as .wav files, coming from 20 different voice actors who spoke each in their home studios with different voice volume. In the game, the different volume of each line comes across as jarring.

How can I best equalize the volumes of all the files so that they the overall voice volume is about the same? My audio engine is FMOD.

---

My ideas:

- Use ffmpeg's volume adjustment to increase the volume of some files. However, I'm concerned this will reduce the quality of the sound.
- Use FMOD to play back different voice lines at different volumes depending on the actor, picking the lowest-volume actor as the baseline. However, I'm concerned that this would put a cap on how loud the game could be even at a computer's highest volume setting.

Comment: This might be a good question for [the Sound Design StackExchange](https://sound.stackexchange.com/search?q=equalize+volume+voice), where you'll find a higher concentration of audio professionals. If you choose to post your question there, be sure to delete the copy here to avoid leaving dead ends for users searching in the future.